# VSCode DevContainer on Windows: cannot create /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-devcontainer

I'm using VSCode on Windows to setup a DevContainer for my application. I'm running Docker Desktop version 4.21.1, VSCode version 1.80.1, and Dev Containers extension version v0.299.0.

My DevContainer is working fine on MacOS, but when I run it on Windows, I got the following error:

```
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.688Z] Stop (1 ms): Run in container: # Test for /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts and ssh
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.688Z] Start: Run in container: # Copy C:\Users\Ali Hamdi Ali Fadel\.ssh\known_hosts to /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.689Z] 
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.689Z] /bin/sh: 71: cannot create /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.689Z] Exit code 2
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.690Z] Stop (2 ms): Run in container: # Copy C:\Users\Ali Hamdi Ali Fadel\.ssh\known_hosts to /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.692Z] Command in container failed: # Copy C:\Users\Ali Hamdi Ali Fadel\.ssh\known_hosts to /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts
(dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=0 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=828 count=1 2>/dev/null) >/home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.692Z] /bin/sh: 71: cannot create /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
[2023-07-25T19:28:54.692Z] Exit code 2
```

I searched all related questions on GitHub and StackOverflow, but nothing worked for me. These are some of the things I tried:

- I tried to start the ssh-agent
- I added the ssh key to the agent
- I gave 777 permissions to the .ssh folder
- I tried `"remoteUser": "vscode"` in the DevContainer settings

Nothing worked for me. Any thoughts on this issue?

PS:

I added `"remoteUser": "root"` to the DevContainer settings and now it works. Any thoughts? Pros/Cons?